# Exceeding the Lambda execution time out after 15 minutes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, salesforce, aws-step-functions

I am exceeding the Lambda execution time out after 15 mins.

The reason why is because I have long running operations that are inserting and updating thousands of rows of data into Salesforce.

Below is the code that is executing one by one:

```
sfdc_ops.insert_case_records( records_to_insert_df , sf)
sfdc_ops.update_case_records( records_to_update_df , sf)
sfdc_ops.update_case_records( unprocessed_in_IKM_df , sf)
sfdc_ops.update_case_records( processed_in_IKM_df , sf)
```

I ultimately do not need to wait for each line. What I really want to do is launch all 4 of these update and insert processes at once.

What is the best solution for avoiding this 15 minute limit - Step Functions?

Comment: What programming language are you using? You could possibly run each of those at the same time, using the asynchronous features of the programming language.

Comment: Can you split out these 4 calls into separate Lambdas?

Comment: @stdunbar Yes - I can send a lambda for an update call and a lambda for an insert call

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) for long-running jobs, such as ETL jobs. You could split the four update operations into separate Lambdas and orchestrate them in a Step Function to run in [parallel](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-parallel-state.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'd rethink your approach. If you're exceeding than 15 minutes limit, then one lambda function isn't going to work for you.

Can you break it down into smaller functionality? One lambda to do the inserts, one to do the updates and orchestrate them using Step Functions perhaps?

Have you looked at AWS Batch for batch processing instead of using Lambda Functions?